# Microsoft Access Total for group

Tags: ms-access, sum, subtotal, grouped-table

I'm trying to figure out how to have a sum that totals all together the totals for each item within a grouped invoice

[See attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVOGP.jpg)

I have multiple grouped invoices on this report and want total for each separate invoice

Comment: Your image - I don't see anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you click "More" on the Invoice row of the grouping pane at the bottom, it should expand some other options. One of those options will say "with no totals" and a drop down arrow. Click the arrow and choose the calculation you would like. I believe this will do what you are looking for. Here is a link for more reference: [MSSupport](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-f23301a1-3e0a-4243-9002-4a23ac0fdbf3)